# Rails - Number of POST request equals number of GET requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, model-view-controller, get, shopping-cart

I'm trying to make this shopping cart app happen, but for some reason it seems like the number of POST request equals the sum of the past GET requests. This results in quite some annoying behaviour!
I can't figure out why.. does anybody have an idea?

ApplicationController:

```
 before_filter :current_delivery
 def current_delivery
   if session[:delivery_id]
      @delivery = Delivery.find(session[:delivery_id])
   else
      @delivery = Delivery.create
      session[:delivery_id] = @delivery.id
   end      
 end
```

OrderItemsController:

```
def create
 @delivery.order_items.new(order_item_params)
 @delivery.save
end
```

ProductsController:

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
  @order_item = OrderItem.new
end
```

Products index:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= render "product_row", product: product %>
<% end %>
```

=> Partial product_row:

```
  <%= form_for @order_item, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.number_field :quantity, value: 1, class: "form-control", min: 1 %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: product.id %>
    <%= f.submit "Add to Cart", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @infused The problem is that too many POST requests are being sent. For example, when I press "Add to Cart", the product gets added too many times..